# how to find it is Folder or File in c# using FTP?

Tags: c#, ftp

When using the Method :

```
   ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
```

I need to find out if the return from the method is either a folder or a file.

Comment: Place a Folder and a File Within that Folder and see what gets returned :)

Comment: see mr.@Johan if i am having xxx.doc as file and vignesh as folder in my FTP. am getting the answer through Stream Reader , evntually am getting both names.For some purpose i need to know whether it is file or folder. Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you should read up on [using FTP in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229718%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you may call `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails` and parse each line. After that depending on the type of FTP server, some char in each line indicates whether the entry is a file or folder (or the first char; it depends on the FTP server; or "date" "indicator" etc. you need to find out the char which indicates it is a file or folder).

If I remember properly, generally the second char of each line indicates whether the entry is a file or a folder.

Comment: Yes,you are correct.But if i use ListDirectoryDetails. i dont know how to parse. if you know how to parse means,Kindly help me @daryal

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7758e7a8-e063-4eec-a6c1-c76a59d02852/listing-all-files-from-ftp-server-using-c